# How to MODIFY a Google Docs document via API using search-and-replace?

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need an example of how to modify an existing document with existing text in Google Docs via API. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text) only shows how to insert and delete text, but not how to update. Have been looking frantically on the web to find examples or a direction on how to do it but without luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out myself.

First, follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTZyuszEkxI) to prepare authentication to the Google Docs API (even though it's about Google Sheets but the process is basically the same). Basically it consists of these steps:

- create project in [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
- enable Google Docs API
- create credentials, including a service account for programmatic access
- share your document with the service account client email address
- install Google API's PHP client: `composer require google/apiclient`

Then create a script like the following:

```php
require_once(__DIR__ .'/vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Some name');  //this name doesn't matter
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ .'/googleapi-credentials.json');  //see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTZyuszEkxI for how to create this file
$service = new \Google_Service_Docs($client);

$documentId = 'YOUR-DOCUMENT-ID-GOES-HERE';  //set your document ID here, eg. "j4i1m57GDYthXKqlGce9WKs4tpiFvzl1FXKmNRsTAAlH"
$doc = $service->documents->get($documentId);

// Collect all pieces of text (see https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure to understand the structure)
$allText = [];
foreach ($doc->body->content as $structuralElement) {
    if ($structuralElement->paragraph) {
        foreach ($structuralElement->paragraph->elements as $paragraphElement) {
            if ($paragraphElement->textRun) {
                $allText[] = $paragraphElement->textRun->content;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Go through and create search/replace requests
$requests = $textsAlreadyDone = $forEasyCompare = [];
foreach ($allText as $currText) {
    if (in_array($currText, $textsAlreadyDone, true)) {
        // If two identical pieces of text are found only search-and-replace it once - no reason to do it multiple times
        continue;
    }

    if (preg_match_all("/(.*?)(dogs)(.*?)/", $currText, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        //NOTE: for simple static text searching you could of course just use strpos()
        // - and then loop on $matches wouldn't be necessary, and str_replace() would be simplified
        $modifiedText = $currText;
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $modifiedText = str_replace($match[0], $match[1] .'cats'. $match[3], $modifiedText);
        }

        $forEasyCompare[] = ['old' => $currText, 'new' => $modifiedText];

        $replaceAllTextRequest = [
            'replaceAllText' => [
                'replaceText' => $modifiedText,
                'containsText' => [
                    'text' => $currText,
                    'matchCase' => true,
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Docs_Request($replaceAllTextRequest);
    }
    $textsAlreadyDone[] = $currText;
}

// you could dump out $forEasyCompare to see the changes that would be made

$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my way - easy one

```
public function replaceText($search, $replace)
{
    $client = $this->getClient();
    $service = new \Google_Service_Docs($client);
    $documentId = ''; // Put your document ID here


    $e = new \Google_Service_Docs_SubstringMatchCriteria();
    $e->text = "{{".$search."}}";
    $e->setMatchCase(false);


    $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'replaceAllText' => array(
            'replaceText' => $replace,
            'containsText' => $e
        ),
    ));

    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
        'requests' => $requests
    ));

    $response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly and across complex items like tables (unlike the accepted answer)